# Not able to create modern team site with group through PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell, modern-experience, office-365-groups

I am trying to create office 365 group through [PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/users-and-groups/new-unifiedgroup?view=exchange-ps). I am using `New-Unified` group function to achieve. Group is creating successfully but unfortunately site is not creating behind the scenes. Is this not the right way to do it?

I have also tried with MSOnline command [New-SPOSite](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/new-sposite?view=sharepoint-ps) to create new modern site. But site is creating but group is not creating behind the scenes. What is wrong with this?

What is the proper way to do it?

Comment: not sure with this, but I am 100% sure if you create a MS team surely it will ceate a Office 365 gruop and a Associated Team site. is this you are looking for.https://www.petri.com/teams-powershell-primer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a Modern team site with associated O365 group using PnP PowerShell.

```
New-PnPSite -Type TeamSite -Title "Test Group" -Alias "TestGroup" -Description "Test group desc" -IsPublic
```

Reference - [New-PnPSite](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/new-pnpsite?view=sharepoint-ps)

If you want create it via MS Graph, PnP PowerShell also supports that. You can provision the Group as below. You need to be Global admin to run this command AFAIK :

```
Connect-PnPOnline - Url "https://tenant.sharepoint.com" -Scopes @("Group.ReadWrite.All", "User.ReadWrite.All", "Directory.ReadWrite.All")

New-PnPUnifiedGroup -DisplayName "Test Group" -Description "Test my group" -MailNickname "Testgroup" -Owners "user@tenant.onmicrosoft.com" -Members "user@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
```

[New-PnPUnifiedGroup](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/new-pnpunifiedgroup?view=sharepoint-ps)

Comment: I have tried with `New-UnifiedGroup` which is not creating modern site for the group. Are you sure this PnP will do the job?

Comment: yes, both will work

Comment: I don't know why, i have created 10 office groups with `New-UnifiedGroup` command. but none of them created modern team site for me

Comment: @Mihir any luck ? did you try the above commands ?

Comment: No luck with these commands

Comment: Any errors? Did you try it as global admin ?

Comment: No errors. Group is creating but not site

Comment: I just tried it via `New-PnPSite` and it works :) , can you maybe try it another tenant and check ?

Comment: Ok thanks. I will check that after new year eve :)

Comment: Happy new year :)  any luck with this ?

Comment: I am busy with another things so couldn't find time to test this. I think this should work as per PnP